# PHP Regex how to match until

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:{A}randomtext{B}{A}randomtext{B}

Basically I want to match strings starting with {A} and ending with {B}.
I currently use this:`~{A}(.+){B}~s`, which gives me this match:{A}randomtext{B}{A}randomtext{B}.

I want it to match strings starting with {A} till the next {B}. How can I do that?

Comment: You'll have to use the non-greedy multipliers.

Comment: I read the linked question and I got it working. Thanks!